# VISA Protocol with Java on Linux

Tags: java, linux, testing, visa

I managed to automatize test equipment using SCPI commands via a TCP/IP socket with these instruments. However I would like to use the VISA library using Java on a Linux machine.
Is there any way to use a VISA library with Java? Should I create my own library?
Any information would be welcome. I am a bit confused about this topic.

Update:
I created my own wrapper with JNI to be able to use from Java code the NI-VISA C Library. It worked well!

Comment: What is VISA library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any VISA library for Java. National Instruments tends to be my first port of call for VISA things and they do not provide one. NI [recommend](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/websearch/802A9D349090D3F5862565CC0076BCF9?OpenDocument) building your own wrapper for the C DLL, which you could consider doing. This might not be overly onerous if you only need limited functionality.

Googling, I came across [someone's project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jvisa/) on Sourceforge where they have tried to do just that, using a Tektronix's VISA DLL - I think you may be able to use their jar file, even if you are not operating a Tektronix instrument. I had a brief look at the projects the guy mentions in "related projects", but I do not think they would be of any use to you, although I might be mistaken.

Comment: I am the author of the above mentioned JNA wrapper around tkVisa64.dll. Our Java application JSeisLab at Colorado School of Mines uses this driver successfully. Right now I tried to use it on a machine that has NiVISA installed, and the wrapper along with tkVisa64.dll does NOT run.

Comment: @Gunter, Yeah, rereading what I wrote I could have been clearer. I would not expect your wrapper to work with NI VISA, but the OP could just use the tkVisa64 dll. Could you confirm it works with non-Tektronix instruments? And is it likely to work on Linux?